# Element-wise comparison of SymPy Matrices

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a convenient way to compare two equal sized SymPy matrices element-wise?

Here's what I'm attempting:

```py
from sympy import Matrix

def element_wise_matrix_comparison(matrix1, matrix2):
    result_matrix = Matrix([[matrix1[i, j] == matrix2[i, j] for j in range(matrix1.shape[1])] for i in range(matrix1.shape[0])])
    return result_matrix
```

While this code works as intended, I wonder if there's a more concise or efficient way to perform this task within SymPy's framework.

Ideally, the comparison should return a boolean Matrix/list/np.array...

Answer (score 2):

Let `A` and `B` be the two symbolic matrices. `A == B` will perform a structural comparison. `A.equals(B)` perform an element-wise mathematical comparison.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import s, t
A = Matrix([[s, t], [s**2, s+2*t]])
B = Matrix([[s, t], [s**2, Add(s, t, t, evaluate=False)]])
A, B
```

[image]

```py
print(A == B) # False, because the last elements of the matrices are structurally different
print(A.equals(B)) # True
```

Comment: surprisingly, the gotchas page doesn't explicitly recommend `.equals()`, but subtracting them when comparing https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html

Comment: Based on the code provided in the question, I think OP wants the result to be a matrix that shows which elements are equal, though having `True`/`False` values in a Sympy matrix is deprecated. I.e. for your example the output would be `Matrix([[True, True],[True, True]])` but if `B[1,1] = s + t`, then it would be `Matrix([[True, True],[True,False]])` (similar to a numpy array equality check). That's just my interpretation.

Comment: Yeah, `equals` tends to be very general and might miss some simplification steps, especially if the expressions are complicated and powers are involved. However, for those expressions, subtracting them together and verifying that they are equal to zero is usually a non-trivial task. I speak from experience :|

Comment: jared is right. Ideally, the comparison should return a boolean Matrix/list/np.array... But it's still a valid answer to my question +1.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `Matrix` from scratch

```
def elementwise_comparison(m1, m2):
    return Matrix(*m1.shape, lambda i, j: m1[i,j] == m2[i,j])
```

---

By delegation of the comparison to `numpy` using `matrix2numpy`

```
from sympy import Matrix, matrix2numpy


def elementwise_comparison(m1, m2, dtype=object) -> numpy.ndarray:
    a1 = matrix2numpy(m1, dtype=dtype)
    a2 = matrix2numpy(m2, dtype=dtype)    
    return a1 == a2
```

Comment: While this does work, I'm not sure it's any better than what OP already has.

Answer (score 1):

Since matrices are iterable it is a bit more compact to write:

```py
a = randMatrix(3,3)
b = Matrix(a); b[1,1] +=x
f = lambda i,j: Symbol("?") if (e:=i.equals(j)) is None else int(e)
>>> ans = Matrix(*a.shape,[f(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]); ans
Matrix([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
```

You could also use an ij-constructor for the result matrix:

```
>>> ans == Matrix(3,3,lambda i,j: f(a[i,j],b[i,j]))
True
```

The function 'f' will display a "?" symbol if the equality is indeterminant. `equals` tries its best given the impossible task it is given.

You could also apply `f` to the difference of the two matrices:

```py
>>> ans == (a-b).applyfunc(lambda x: f(x,0))
True
```